# What is the role of Win32 in modern Windows architecture?

Tags: windows, winapi

At Microsoft BUILD conference, I saw this figure.

I'm wondering whether the position of Win32 is correct or not. What is the role and position of Win32 API in modern Windows architecture?

My concept of Win32 API is a sort of assembly of all modern Windows architecture. Win32 API (or DDK) bridges "Windows Kernel Services" to the other technologies.

I thought that Internet Explorer/.NET/Silverlight are all build *upon* Win32 API. Even if a fancy new Metro Apps, I conjecture that Win32 is at the bottom place. However, this figure defies my knowledge.

As you can see, IE/.NET/SL/Metro are sitting horizontally with Win32.

Questions:

1. Does this figure necessarily mean that Win32 is *not* the framework of all other modern technologies?
2. What is "Windows Kernel Services"? How programmers can access them? Isn't it through Win32 API and DDK?

[image: Windows 8 Platform]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The diagram is wrong.

While there were originally other subsystems (e.g. POSIX) which accessed `ntdll.dll` (the "Kernel Services" gateway) without going through Win32 (`kernel32.dll`, `user32.dll`) these are all now defunct.

All modern application frameworks for Windows are built on Win32.  The other subsytems are no longer supported.  In some cases (drivers, and boot-time system utilities such as chkdsk) code is written directly against the native API, but these scenarios are very rare.

I'm not very familiar with WinRT, but I think Win32 fits underneath it as well (or it may use a combination of Win32 and direct `ntdll.dll` services).

According to [Sasha Goldshtein](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/sasha/archive/2011/09/15/winrt-and-net-in-windows-8.aspx),

> Next, a C++ Metro application will still load Win32 DLLs such as kernel32 and ntdll. Moreover, the WinRT APIs call into the Win32 DLLs – so they are not a replacement but rather a wrapper, an API flavor, on top of Win32. (Historical note: Windows used to have a feature called “environment subsystems”, which can be roughly described as API flavors. WinRT is not an environment subsystem – it is a library on top of the Win32 environment subsystem.)

Comment: +1; currently on Windows without Win32 you can't even create a window (you can *draw* with just DirectX, but it won't be a window as the others). And I don't know about WinRT, but surely IE and the .NET Framework use a lot of Win32 APIs (and not just ntdll).

Comment: The diagram isn't wrong, it just isn't applicable to versions of Windows prior to Windows 8.

Comment: @Harry: I'd believe that the author wasn't really interested in showing how the Win32 subsystem relates to everything else, but I'm just not believing IE built directly on the native interface.  Rewriting it in .NET, I'd believe, but not the way the diagram is now.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean.  No, that part of the diagram probably isn't complete - that's implementation detail, after all, which doesn't matter to the developer.

Comment: Thanks! I'm totally agree with you. But, this post (http://www.winsupersite.com/blog/supersite-blog-39/windows8/winrt-replacing-win32-140605) also confuses me. It claims that WinRT replaces Win32. I'm still highly doubt such major changes could be done in Windows Version 6.2.

Comment: @minjang: In that case, it's most likely a new name for the next edition of the Win32 API, and not actually a replacement.  Microsoft has certainly done that before (OLE Automation, COM, DCOM, ActiveX, COM+ are all different versions of the same technology, not different technologies).  But the little I've heard is that it augments Win32 rather than replacing it.  Most Win32 features don't even interact directly with the kernel, they're layered on top of `kernel32.dll` which in turn uses `ntdll.dll`.  I expect new APIs to be the same way.

Comment: http://www.infoq.com/news/2011/09/WinRT-API WinRT looks like a real replacement of Win32. So, the above diagram is half right and wrong.

Comment: @minjang: So you can't consume both WinRT and Win32 from the same application?  That's not good, look at how often .NET apps need to p/invoke Win32.  And the lack of support for overlapped windows is just crazy.

Comment: I simply created a Metro C++ app, and saw the class stack. In the bottom, yes it's still ntdll/kerner32. It also uses combase.dll. So, it's now clear, though I can't say WinRT is totally upon Win32, but at leasat, it should use Win32 APIs. (Unfortunately, symbols in DLLs are not resolved yet.)

Comment: @minjang: Ok, that makes more sense.  Win32 has so many layers anyway.  So it sounds like they're keeping the lowest layer (kernel32.dll) to interface with the native API (ntdll.dll), but providing an alternate windowing toolkit (WPF-style instead of User32/GDI/OpenGL/DirectX).  Wonder how easy it is to e.g. mix Metro UI with traditional winsock for networking?  Probably not very, because user32 message handling was pretty well integrated with everything else, via `MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx`; if that's not used with Metro then using many Win32 APIs will be tricky.

Comment: @minjang: Found a more authoritative source.

Answer (score 1):

The diagram is (presumably) correct, but only for Windows 8.  Windows 8 has a significantly different architecture from previous versions.

I believe applications can make requests directly to the kernel, but the interface is mostly undocumented.  Device drivers use the kernel directly.